# Getting wrong datetime format from SQL

Tags: php, sql, iis

I have two Windows 2008 servers with IIS, PHP and MSSQL.

In a PHP-script, I query a table with a field of type 'datetime':

```
SELECT timestamp FROM table
```

Now the problem is, that on one server I get this format:

> 2012-02-05 12:32:54.020

But on the other server I get this (which I don´t want):

> Feb 5 2012  12:32PM

When querying through SQL Server Management Studio I get the 'correct' (2012-02-05 12:32:54.020) value on both servers.

**My question is:**
How do I disable this conversion in PHP so that the format returned is always in this format: 2012-02-05 12:32:54.020?

**Edit:** I know that I could change the script to format the date, but I don't want to go through 10000+ files. What is causing this conversion? Is it PHP, SQL or IIS? It is working on the old server, so I assume it could work on the new server.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can format the date with [`date_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) like this:

```
$correctDate = date_format($dateToFormat, "Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that I would have to go through 10000+ files to insert this code, which obviously worked on the old server. I think that it is a setting in PHP, which i missed?

Answer (score 0):

You may format it on server side:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, timestamp, 121) FROM table
```

Comment: The problem with this is, that I would have to go through 10000+ files. It is working on the old server, so I assume that it could also work on the new server. Maybe it is a setting in PHP, which I missed?